# jQuery code didn't run on my plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery

I use this to hook my scripts and styles to my plugin:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'the_box_init' );

// Init plugin options to white list our options
function the_box_init(){
    register_setting( 'the_box_options', 'the_box', 'the_box_validate' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myprefix-style', plugins_url('theboxstyle.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myprefix-script', plugins_url('theboxjs.js', __FILE__) ); //this hook my custom js, preferrably which contents almost my jquery codes.

}
```

However, the jQuery code doesn't work; even this simple code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
alert("asdasd");
});
```

Only plain JavaScript did work.

What do you suppose went wrong in my implementation that jQuery doesn't work?

I'm open to any suggestions, recommendations and ideas.

Comment: your browser's javascript error console will likely tell you the problem, read the section titled [jQuery noConflict Wrappers for `wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers). also, [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) is the correct action to add admin scripts and styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the DOM for the theboxjs.js and see if it is loaded correctly (check the output path). If not then you have path issues.

Try using `admin_enqueue_scripts` instead of `admin_init` for loading scripts.

You might also have conflict in your script. When writing scripts for WP try to avoid `$` and use `jQuery` instead.